# Alfresco share repository section not working

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I installed fresh **Alfresco 7.1.1**. Everything is working fine except the repository section is not working properly in the share. I am able to create the sites and user but when I go to repository or site document library it shows the following.

[image]

I sent a document to the repository and it got created successfully. Even I can access the document using the Admin Console Node browser and see all the folders like **company_home**.

There are no documents or icons to create a new content. I tried to drag and drop the document but that also did not work.

My tomcat is running on **8081** and I have replaced all the ***localhost:8080*** ports in the **share-config-custom.xml** with **localhost:8081**.

Comment: Any error in log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I did not installed the Alfresco-Share-Services.amp. However it was not showing any warnings in the logs about not having Alfresco-Share-Services.amp installed.

Than you everyone for their time.

Answer (score 0):

This will also occur if you accidentally install the Alfresco-share-services.amp to the share.war. It needs to be installed to the alfresco.war file. The module will show as installed but it will not allow you see the repositories in the screen shot on this question.  It took a little while for me to debug my miss-step in installation so trying to save others some time if they make the same mistake.